# Закрыть модальное окно по событию

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите пожалуйста закрыть модальное окно при клике по кнопке butReset

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def reset():
     #win.destroy()
     pass

def modal():
     win = Toplevel(root)

     butReset = Button(win, text = 'close modal win', command = reset())
     butReset.pack()

button = Button(root, text = 'open modal', command = modal)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы вы могли управлять окном, необходимо его обхявить вне функции. 
Но так как Toplevel появляется автоматически, даже без упаковки, то как вариат его заранее определить и просто скрыть, а кнопками показывать, или опять скрывать. 
Как-то так:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

def modal(event):
     win = Toplevel(root)
     def reset(event):
          win.destroy()
     butReset = Button(win, text = 'close modal win')
     butReset.bind("<Button-1>", reset)
     butReset.pack()

button = Button(root, text = 'open modal')
button.bind("<Button-1>", modal)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

P.S.: поправил ответ. В предыдущем случае, если пользователь нажмет кнопку "Закрыть"(крестик в углу), вместо кнопки "close modal win", тогда при попытке создать модальное окно заново выскочит ошибка. 
В новом же решении мы создаем окошко и его уничтожаем при помощи вложенной функции, просто-напросто.

Comment: конечно хотелось бы научиться уничтожать не заранее созданные окна, а созданные в процессе хода программы. но и такое решение подошло в моём случае. спасибо

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin а кто мешает?