# как после нажатия на красный крестик вывести сообщение

Tags: python, tkinter

Надо было чтобы по нажатию на красный крестик окна tkinter, который должен закрыть окно , вылетало сообщение `messagebox.askyesno()`

Comment: Ваш вопрос похож на этот посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/291044/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()

def on_close():
    if messagebox.askokcancel('Выход', 'Действительно хотите закрыть окно?'):
        root.destroy()


root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_close)
root.mainloop()
```